# Нашёл у гостиницы веник(,) зудьбе-прохиндейке назло

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые?

> Нашёл у гостиницы веник(,) зудьбе-прохиндейке назло.

> Нашёл веник(,) зудьбе-прохиндейке назло,  у гостиницы веник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Если мы подчëркиваем оборот интонацией с целью пояснения, запятые ставим**:

*Нашёл (веник), зудьбе-прохиндейке назло, у гостиницы (веник)*;

*Нашёл у гостиницы веник, зудьбе-прохиндейке назло*.

**Если не подчëркиваем, запятые не ставим**:

*Нашёл у гостиницы веник зудьбе-прохиндейке назло*;

*Нашёл (веник) зудьбе-прохиндейке назло, у гостиницы (веник)*.

**Так же может выделяться оборот *у гостиницы (если подчëркивается)***:

*Нашёл (веник)..., у гостиницы, (веник)*;

*Нашёл, у гостиницы, веник...*

**Соответственно, не выделяем, если не подчëркиваем**_:

*Нашёл (веник)... у гостиницы (веник)*;

*Нашёл у гостиницы веник...*.

Так же могут подчëркиваться **оба оборота** — а соответственно, и выделяться, — а может и **ни один из них**.

В общем, вариантов миллион, и всë это зависит напрямую **от автора**.

Подробности здесь[, в справочнике Розенталя (*обстоятельства, выраженные существительными; обстоятельства, выраженные наречиями*)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112).

Comment: По он же *феник* говорит!

Comment: А почему ***з**удьба*-то? От слова "зуд", что ли? Это ведь не акунинский вариант: *— Это мой злой зудьба, — тихо бубнил слуга из-за плеча Зеппа. — Я есть не везущий человек. Зовсем не везущий…* ("Смерть на брудершафт").